# Selecting multiple ACLs for a menu item

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Joomla 2.5

You can select only one ACL for a menu item.

Let's say I have groups:

- group1
- group2
- group3
- group4
- group5

And ACLs

- ACL1 (contains group1)
- ACL2 (contains group2)
- ACL3 (contains group3)
- ACL4 (contains group4)
- ACL5 (contains group5)

Now I need to attribute to menu items some combinations of ACLs.

Let's say

- MenuItem1 visible by group1 and group2
- MenuItem2 visible by group1 and group5
- MenuItem3 visible by group3 and group5
- etc...

To achieve this I need to create a lot of ACLs that will satisfy my needed combinations of groups:

- ACL6 for MenuItem1 (contains group1 and group2)
- ACL7 for MenuItem2 (contains group1 and group5)
- ACL8 for MenuItem3 (contains group3 and group2)
- etc...

And this is really uncomfortable.

Is there a way (or an extension) that would permit to attribute multiple ACLs for a menu item (without creating new ACLs that would reflect the needed group combinations)?

Comment: Do you use ACL groups : http://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List/1.6-2.5/Tutorial#Default_Groups . Otherwise explain what you really want to do.

Comment: you can attribute only one ACL to a specific menu item. I am looking how I can attribute more than one ACL to a menu item, instead of creating a new ACLs

Comment: I don't think Joomla ACL has been thinked this way. So maybe there is an extension that does what you want, but I'm not sure you can do what you want with a standard Joomla. But nice question that deserves +1. ;)

Comment: edited the question to be more explicit

Comment: You need to make a new view level that only includes the groups you want. Then assign that view level to you menu item.

SO
ACL6, ACL7, ACL8 etc are view levels.
groups are user groups to which users may be assigned.
Attach the user groups to the view level.

Comment: Elin: this is what i already mentioned, I need to assign multiple acls

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to create multiple menu items, each assigned with the group you need. Otherwise, the way you are doing it with parent ACL groups is the way to go.